# While using SP_ExecuteSQL I'm generating a boolean error

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, boolean, concatenation

I'm very new to SQL, so let me first apologize if my questions come off as trivial or it seems as though I haven't done my work. I am trying to learn how to grasp a lot of these concepts.

Anyway, I'm writing a complex query that will eventually take many parameters. For these parameters I'll be using a comma delimited string to allow multiple variables. (I've solved this issue previously, but not when attempting to execute an `SP_ExecuteSQL`.

With that being said, here is the bare bones of the query.

```
DECLARE @system_status varchar(30)
SELECT @system_status = '12,14'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)


SELECT @sql = 'SELECT  [system_status]
  FROM VW_Document_Main      
  WHERE 1=1 ' 

IF @System_Status =  '-1'      
      Begin      
            SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and system_status <> 20'      
      End      
ELSE IF @system_status IS NOT NULL AND @system_status NOT IN ('-1','0')      
      Begin     
            SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and ' + @system_Status + ' LIKE ''%,'' + system_Status + '',%'''
```

I'm able to populate a useable query when not building it into an sp_executesql statement, however, since I'll be building about this query it's necessary to take these steps... any thoughts as to why I'm generating the non-Boolean error?

EDIT: Not sure if it's a step in the right direction, but now after reworking the final SELECT statement to read:

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and '',''' + @system_Status + '','''  LIKE ''%,' + 'system_Status' + ',%'''
```

It's giving me back a different error:  A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

It should be worth noting that the error reads: **An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.**

Comment: @system_status is a varchar, but you have 'and system_status <> 20' without single quotes around 20. I don't know if that's your only problem, but you need to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

You're plugging in your literal @system_status value '12, 14' into the final SQL so it looks like this

```
SELECT [system_status] FROM VW_Document_Main WHERE 1=1 and 12,14 LIKE '%,' + system_Status + ',%'
```

Which will fail because you don't have 12,14 in quotes. So you'll have to modify the line

```
SELECT @system_status = '12,14'
```

to be

```
SELECT @system_status = '''12,14'''
```

Alternatively, since you said you're running this through sp_executeSql you should modify your last select to

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and  @system_Status LIKE ''%,'' + system_Status + '',%'''
```

And change your execute SQL proc to

```
sp_executesql @sql, N'@system_status varchar(30)', @system_status
```

Comment: It's running the query without any errors, but still affecting 0 rows. Even if I'm just using a single variable.. hmmm

Comment: And there is a definitely a row returned when you run SELECT [system_status] FROM VW_Document_Main where system_status like '%,12,14,%'